# How does one reset Rhythmbox for a new library?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

Previous similar questions have provided answers but the answers don't work for Ubuntu 12.04 and Rhythmbox 2.98.

I have an SD card with an extensive music library.  I have renamed unknown track titles to the correct track titles on the SD card with the file browser.  I have also changed a different album with unknown track titles to the correct titles by editing Rhythmbox properties.  These are retained by Rhythmbox but not changed on the SD card which still shows only the track number.  I now want to reset the Rhythmbox library to the edited SD card containing all the correct track titles.

Using answers from previous questions I have removed `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`.  I then import the new library on the SD card.  Titles renamed on the SD card with the file browser are not imported and titles changed by editing Rythmbox properties are still there.  No reset has occurred.

I have also removed `~/.cache/rhythmbox` as suggested in previous answers to no avail.

Previous answers also suggest removing `~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox`.  This directory does no exist on Ubuntu 12.04.

Does anyone have any new ideas on how to reset the Rhythmbox library with Ubuntu 12.04 and Rhythmbox 2.98?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start over again with Rhythmbox you could un + re-install.

First you want to purge (instead of remove) in order to delete not only the program but also the configuration files: `sudo dpkg --purge rhythmbox`

Then you can re-install rhythmbox: `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

Comment: This thing doesn't help at all. I just uninstalled Rhythmbox, I runned `locate rhythmbox | grep $USER` and it seem that I still have `~/.cache/rhythmbox` and `~/.local/share/rhythmbox` directories and the things from image attached to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)[image: Install dconf].

Open **dconf-editor** (search for it in Dash) and browseto **org** > **gnome** > **rhythmbox**, expand and see what you can adjust or set back to default there.

[image: dconf]